# Socle of a Hamiltonian group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, direct-product, socle

Currently I am studying the definition of Socle of a group. Also, I came to know that Socle of a finite nilpotent group $G$ is the product of elementary abelian $p$-groups for the collection of primes dividing the order of $G$. I know that Hamiltonian groups are nilpotent of class $2$. Now, I am wondering what can be the Socle of a Hamiltonian group. More precisely, I have the following question.

Let $H$ be an infinite Hamiltonian group, that is, $H$ is an infinite non-abelian group all of whose subgroups are normal. What is the Socle of $H$, $\mathrm{Soc}(H)$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please share what you have tried

Comment: I know that infinite non-abelian Hamiltonian group H is the direct sum of a quaternion group Q8, an elementary abelian 2-group B and a torsion abelian group with all elements of odd order D. From here, I am trying to show that Socle is the direct product of cyclic group of order 2, B and some subgroup of D.

Comment: This does have context, though, @beingmathematician; see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28072/104041).

Comment: In general ${\rm Soc}(G \times H) = {\rm Soc}(H) \times {\rm Soc}(H)$.

Comment: I didn't know that held in general, @DerekHolt. Where might I find a proof? I couldn't find it anywhere . . .

Comment: @DerekHolt Can you please provide references so that I can see the proof of the in general result that youposted?

Comment: I searched for "socle of direct product of groups" and found that I had already answered this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2942103)!  That question was about finite groups, but the proof does assume finiteness.

Comment: Thank you, @DerekHolt!

Comment: @DerekHolt Can we apply the result then for this problem regarding Hamiltonian group?

Comment: Yes we can, we can apply it to the three direct factors of $H$ that you mentioned and derive the result you want. ${\rm Soc}(Q_8) = C_2$, ${\rm Soc}(B)=B$, and ${\rm Soc}(D)$ is generated by the elements of prime order in $D$.

Comment: Can you provide me some references where I can find the result, namely, $Soc(G \times H) = Soc(G) \times Soc(H)$? I understand the proof of yours in math stack exchange. But I am surprised that I could not find its references in any of the textbooks.